# Gstreamer Windows build occurs "fatal error LNK1181 jpeg.lib"

Tags: windows, build, gstreamer

I build gstream source following [this](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/#windows-prerequisites-setup) instruction.
"meson setup builddir" command will work, but "meson compile -C builddir" command occurs fatal error.erro detail is below.

> FAILED: subprojects/gst-plugins-base/ext/gl/gstopengl.dll
> subprojects/gst-plugins-base/ext/gl/gstopengl.pdb "link"
> @subprojects/gst-plugins-base/ext/gl/gstopengl.dll.rsp LINK : fatal
> error LNK1181: 入力ファイル 'jpeg.lib' を開けません。 [990/4012] Compiling C object
> subprojects/gst-plugins-base/ext/pango/gstpango.dll.p/gstbasetextoverlay.c.obj
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.